# Facebook page /feed missing images

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using the Facebook Public API Feed for the longest time and since they deprecated it I've been trying to find a replacement method in C#.

I am able to get my page posts but any post that contains images I only get the message and no images. After spending the past weekend trying to find a way I am desperate to know if anyone has had any success in getting full page post content from the Facebook C# SDK library.

Here is what I have and it works for getting the posts but they do not contain any images.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient
{
    AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FacebookAppID"),
    AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FacebookAppSecret"),
    AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FacebookAccessToken")
};

var pageFeed = string.Format("/v2.4/{0}/feed", _facebookPageId);
dynamic response = fb.Get(pageFeed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the upgrade in Graph API v2.4. Only a limited set of data is sent via FB unless specifically requested. You should pass the `fields` parameter with the keyword of data which you would like to retrieve.

A list of keyword is available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post)

In your case, the request statement would be:

```
var pageFeed = string.Format("/v2.4/{0}/feed?fields=id,message,picture", _facebookPageId);
```

To get all pictures from a post: replace `picture` with `attachments`, as `picture` will return the very first picture linked to the post.

```
var pageFeed = string.Format("/v2.4/{0}/feed?fields=id,message,attachments", _facebookPageId);
```

Comment: actually, that is a change that happened with v2.4, not with v2.0. see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: picture seems to only get me a single photo from the post, I don't see any keyword to get all photos in a post. Is that correct that it only supports a single photo?

Comment: @devfunkd I've updated the answer. Please have a look.